# Learning Symfony 5 and having trouble with Bootstrap integration via Webpack and Encore and having weird issues with the CSS

Tags: symfony, webpack, bootstrap-4, webpack-encore, symfony5

Here I am, going back to Symfony after leaving it for the past few years. Now it's using Webpack when it used to  Assetic last time I touched it. So, I am a bit confused with a lot of things related to the  rapidly evolving JavaScript ecosystem.

I went to Sensiolabs's website to follow instructions on  how to integrate Bootstrap to my project. I went pretty far in the process as I have a link to my stylesheet on my webpage :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Blog index!</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/app.css">
    </head>
<body class="bg-light">
```

When I use the path for the css as an url : http://localhost/symfony-01/public/build/app.css
I'm getting all the styles displayed (correctly, I assume).
However, I am not getting any styling at all in the html. At first I thought  I hadn't generated the build with webapp correctly but it's not the case.

So I added some silly element to the twig template and gave it a silly css as to make sure style was not overloaded or something: 
in base.html.twig:

```
<div class="superfuzz"> HELLO GUYS</div>
```

And in app.css :

```
div.superfuzz{
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

When I look at the css I get from url above, I can go down and find that style wasindeed added By Encore. Yet style in inspector is empty, it's not applied. I dont know why, it's a total mystery to me. The only idea I have would be that the link to the stylesheet is not correct but at the same time I am pretty new with webpack, Encore, and Yarn.

Could also mean the style in the css file is not correct. I haven't done that much SCSS to really spot if something wrong but normally webpack is converting it in correct css right?

Here is the twig version of my html header, just in case :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block stylesheets %}
        {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body class="bg-light">
```

Here is my webpack.config.js :

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', [
        './assets/js/app.js',
        './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js',
        './node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js',
        './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'])

    // .addStyleEntry('css/app', [
    //     './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
    //    './assets/css/app.css'
    // ])

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })
    .enableSassLoader()

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    //.enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    //.autoProvidejQuery()

    // uncomment if you use API Platform Admin (composer req api-admin)
    //.enableReactPreset()
    //.addEntry('admin', './assets/js/admin.js')
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

And let me add assets/js/app.js:

```
import '../css/global.scss';
import '../css/app.css';

// Need jQuery? Install it with "yarn add jquery", then uncomment to import it.
// import $ from 'jquery';

const $ = require('jquery');
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
```

And scss file:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Content of the entrypoints.json file:

```
{
  "entrypoints": {
    "app": {
      "js": [
        "/build/runtime.js",
        "/build/vendors~app.js",
        "/build/app.js"
      ],
      "css": [
        "/build/app.css"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your app.js entry point imports your css/scss file?

Comment: Yes, I will append app.js to the question.

Comment: Are you watching the files (so it rebuilds when you change the source) aka "yarn watch"? If you look into your app.css file do you see the div.superfuzz class?

Comment: No I am not. I did try using the watch option on the Encore command but now I relaunch it when I am changing something. And yes when I look in the app.css file built by webpack I see it... I just added this class and this div as a sure test but actually I am not seeing any styling on any dom element, Not even those styles that belong to Bootstrap, even though I seem them all in the css file that is linked; To be honest, it's the first time I seeing this kind of error with external css files. It really looks like the link rel is not done properly.

Comment: My previous post inspired me to investigate this further. And I found something.  I went to the css link tag in theinspector and right click and chose "open in style editor" but instead of styles I got a html page with a 404 message "The requested URL was not found on this server." So clearly the link's href attribute is set wrong. I suspected that even though the full path http://localhost/symfony-01/public/build/app.css was working. the href path "/build/app.css might be wrong. Or something else might block the app like for instance, I haven't set a virtual host yet for this app?

Comment: Can you show the URL that returns 404? At least the part that comes after the domain. I suspect that you are missing the json_manifest_path key from your assets config

Comment: Ah that's interesting.  the url generated is http://localhost/build/app.css,  The project folder and public folder are missing, I didnt find the json file you mentioned but the Symfony documentation mentions the entrypoints.json file that is used to generate the link and the script tags. I am appending its content to my question.

Comment: What is the URL for your index?

Comment: Actually I realize I didnt spot the manifest.json file right beneath the entrypoints.json file but i's not helping much. URL for index.php is http://localhost/symfony-01/public/index.php

Comment: Try changing your public path to /symfony-01/pubilc/build .setPublicPath('/symfony-01/pubilc/build') on line 11 of your webpack config. Note that this would most likely be different in production so you'll have to make sure the config is right for prod as well

Comment: I have tried editing both json files by hand but the app is not making things easy for me. If I run Encore after editing, my changes are reset. If I add the missing part (symfony-01/public) of the URL with a relative path, the application adds the missing part a second time unless path is starting with a forward slash to make it root-relative. I realized the basic paths were root relative so I thought if I remove this forward slash on the generated path it would append the missing part but actually it seems to convert it into a root relative path anyhow.

Comment: You should not edit files in the build directory manually. As for your public path, see https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/faq.html#my-app-lives-under-a-subdirectory

Comment: Yes indeed, actually I just noticed your comment after I sent mine. And your solution works! Yes! you should make it a reply so I can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Well the solution is very specific to your setup... Maybe you should answer your own question ;)

Comment: Ok thank you anyway :)

Comment: BTW your setup might be wrong, I don't see your folder structure, but the symfony app should not normally be accessible from the web, your documentroot should normally be your public folder

Answer (score 0):

Ok the generated link href path was incorrect.
Thanks to @Julien B. for providing the solution.

As I am not using a virtualhost yet, my URL is following the localhost/projetfolder/public format. I had too much trust in Encore handling this right off the bat but actually I had to edit the parameter to the setPublicPath method in webpack.config.js to reflect my situation. So it must be .setPublicPath('/projectfolder/public/build') instead of .setPublicPath('/build')

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the cache when you have changed something.
I had the similar problem with this files. Symfony couldn't find this files:

```
http://localhost/build/runtime.js
http://localhost/build/vendors~app.js
http://localhost/build/app.js
```

The problem had disappeared after this:

```
bin/console cache:clear; npm run watch
```